# No option for Scheduler in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

[No Scheduler Option available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76gex.png)

I do not have the option to schedule jobs in SQL Developer. How can I enable it?

Comment: Can anyone please help me with my query

Comment: Check under Tools > Features... and look under Database to see if the Scheduler feature is checked. (I'm not sure why it wouldn't be - I'm not too familiar with SQL Dev but I do have a copy.)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, this worked for me : [SQL developer refine connections view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213728/sql-developer-refine-connections-view)

tldr; Tools>Preferences>Database>Navigation filter

"Navigation filter" seems a bit misleading at first

Comment: It does not answer the question, because there's nothing about scheduling

Comment: There is a whole branch of them :  check the screenshot from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38214588/2549836)
You can clearly see the scheduler check box which displays the schedulings menus on the connection view