# SQL developer refine connections view

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I searched about this on google and so, but could not find a solution:

I am working on Oracle SQL developer using multiple schemas and database connections. Lets say i have connection 1 which has schema 1 and table 1. Then i have connection 2, which has schema 2 and table 2, and so on...

Every now and then i have to lookup information in table 1 then table2, .... and so  on... which means a lot of navigation, scrolling etc. on my small laptop screen. it would make the life much easier if there was a way to hide the unwanted schema objects. For example, i only need to work with tables, don't need views, procedures, Indexes, Triggers etc. to be visible (on the left hand menu-> under connections) - that will reduce the scrolling a lot and hopefully i would be able to see tables under connection 1 and tables under connection 2 in single view(without scrolling). Is there a way to remove these unwanted objects from the view?

Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question, but i am not SQL-developer-savvy, so any help is greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: you can also navigate to an object directly from an editor, by ctrl+mouse hover+clicking on the object name if you've typed it out - easier than navigating the tree or even the Schema Browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Preferences dialog

Go to the Database page

find, navigation filtering

enable the feature on the right bottom, then uncheck what you don't want to browse

[image]

Comment: awesome, if you have more questions, don't be shy!

Answer (score 1):

When You have connections to different systems, eg. DEV, TEST, INTEGRATION, PRODUCTION it may additionally be helpful to organize each of these target systems into different folders. Just context-click (for me it's a left click, as my mouse is lefthanded) to the connection, then choose ADD TO FOLDER.

As I guess you will have the same schemata in all those connections, this help you to avoid to connection to the wrong system by accident.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another alternative method to work with, is to use the "Schema_Browser" in SQL-Developer.

It opens a separate Tab for each connection, where you can select just the objects from the connected schema. Instead of scrolling between different schemas, it means, working only within the Tab of each connection.

To open it, just go to "Connections", and right-click on the wanted schema.
Then select "Schema Browser". You will see just one kind of objects.

[image: Open Schema Browser]

Since "Tables" are already the default object, it might be a good alternative for you.